# How to compute the centroid of a mesh with triangular faces without using Blender's built-in functions?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, faces, measurement

I do not want to use Blender's built-in functions for computing centroids as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin) as it seems that they do not give me the kind of centroid I expect to get. I want to compute a new centroid for my meshes given the following description. First, I want to compute the centers of faces (triangle) of a mesh centroid of a mesh. Then I need to compute the faces area. The new centroid is the average of the mesh faces' centers, weighted by their area. How can I do this using Blender's Python API?

Comment: I've assumed by _without using Blender built in functions_ you mean without using the transform origin operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bmesh approach**

The bmesh module has for faces the methods to calculate [centre](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFace.calc_center_median) and [area](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFace.calc_area).

There are three methods to calculate the centre of the face.

> **`calc_center_bounds()`**
>
> ```
> Return bounds center of the face.
> Returns:  a 3D vector.
> Return type:  mathutils.Vector
> ```
>
> **`calc_center_median()`**
>
> ```
> Return median center of the face.
> Returns:  a 3D vector.
> Return type:  mathutils.Vector
> ```
>
> **`calc_center_median_weighted()`**
>
> ```
> Return median center of the face weighted by edge lengths.
> Returns:  a 3D vector.
> Return type:  mathutils.Vector
> ```

I've used `calc_center_median()` for $x_i$ and **[`BMFace.calc_area()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFace.calc_area)** for the weight $w_i$ for each face of index $i$ the weighted mean is

$$\tilde x = \frac {w_0x_0 + w_1x_1 + ... + w_nx_n}{w_0 + w_1 + ... + w_n}$$

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
context = bpy.context

ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

weights = [f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces]
weighted_centres = [f.calc_area() * f.calc_center_median() 
        for f in bm.faces]

local_weighted_mean = sum(weighted_centres, Vector()) / sum(weights)
print(local_weighted_mean)

# set as new origin
for v in bm.verts:
    v.co -= local_weighted_mean
mw = ob.matrix_world
mw.translation = mw * local_weighted_mean
bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()
```

[image]
*Result of running on newly added Suzanne. Scene cursor shows old origin.*

Note: if modifiers are used on the object to triangulate, or subdivide, can (for example) use

```
bm.from_object(ob, context.scene, render=True)
```

to calculate weighted origin of modified mesh.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with some simple math

```
import bpy
import mathutils


def unit_normal(vert1, vert2, vert3):
    determinant = mathutils.Vector((
        mathutils.Matrix((
            (1.0, vert1[1], vert1[2]),
            (1.0, vert2[1], vert2[2]),
            (1.0, vert3[1], vert3[2]))).determinant(),
        mathutils.Matrix((
            (vert1[0], 1.0, vert1[2]),
            (vert2[0], 1.0, vert2[2]),
            (vert3[0], 1.0, vert3[2]))).determinant(),
        mathutils.Matrix((
            (vert1[0], vert1[1], 1.0),
            (vert2[0], vert2[1], 1.0),
            (vert3[0], vert3[1], 1.0))).determinant()))
    return determinant.normalized()

def calc_area_of_polygon(mesh, polygon):
    total = mathutils.Vector((0.0,0.0,0.0))
    last_vertex = mathutils.Vector(mesh.vertices[polygon.vertices[-1]].co)
    for vertex in polygon.vertices:
        this_vertex = mathutils.Vector(mesh.vertices[vertex].co)
        total += this_vertex.cross(last_vertex)
        last_vertex = this_vertex
    result = total.dot(unit_normal(
        mesh.vertices[polygon.vertices[0]].co,
        mesh.vertices[polygon.vertices[1]].co,
        mesh.vertices[polygon.vertices[2]].co,
    ))
    return abs(result/2)
def calc_center_of_polygon(mesh: bpy.types.Mesh, polygon: bpy.types.MeshPolygon):
    result = mathutils.Vector()
    for vertex in polygon.vertices:
        result += mathutils.Vector(mesh.vertices[vertex].co)
    return result / len(polygon.vertices)


def calc_center(mesh: bpy.types.Mesh):
    total_weight = 0.0
    total_center = mathutils.Vector()
    for polygon in mesh.polygons:
        weight = calc_area_of_polygon(mesh, polygon)
        total_weight += weight
        total_center += weight * calc_center_of_polygon(mesh, polygon)
    return total_center / total_weight

print(calc_center(bpy.data.meshes['Cube']))
```

Comment: Your code actually has some bugs. It gives very incorrect numbers.

Comment: I reviewed your changes. But please be aware that you need to use the `bpy.types.Mesh` object like in the last line of the example. In your review you wanted to use it by using `bpy.types.Object` which is not my intention so I rejected it. Sorry if my try gave some bad results.

Comment: Oops, apologies on my part for the se approval, thought it was mostly Re: [vertex vs vertice _"crime"_](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/can-a-punishment-be-implemented-for-using-the-word-vertice-in-a-q-a) didn't get as far as to see the `mesh.data` edit.  Will check more carefully in future.

Comment: @batFINGER no problem. will update the `vertex` stuff :-)

Answer (score 0):

Update for newer versions of blender (I'm running 3.6)

@batFINGER 's answer worked for me but I had to switch:

`mw.translation = mw * local_weighted_mean`

with:

`mw.translation = mw @ local_weighted_mean`

due to an error "Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector' types"