# Center a mesh from a ply file in the origin

Tags: mesh, shortcut

Is there a quick way to move the baricenter of a given mesh to the origin in blender?

Like a shortcut?

Comment: Little unclear what you are asking. Do you mean the centre of mass of the object?  A [barycenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter)  implies two objects [example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91455/i-am-trying-to-make-an-animation-of-a-double-planet-cant-seem-to-get-it-right)  TO move the origin of the object to be at (0, 0, 0)  apply location (ctrl-A location.)

Comment: What I'm asking is intuitive actually... Compute the barycenter of your mesh (sum of vertices divided by their number) and translate the whole mesh by a quantity -barycenter.

Comment: Summed  vert coordinates divided by number of verts is geometric origin. [Related ?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101490/how-to-compute-the-centroid-of-a-mesh-with-triangular-faces-without-using-blende)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the following schortcuts maybe you will find what you need.

Shift+S = Snap

Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C = Set Origin

Comment: You can also press numeric sequential  positions to select each of the options shown in those menu, eg: Shift+S+5 will select "cursor to selected"